# Will the badges ever have a design to them instead of just having colors?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, badges

Right now there are simply the colors of Silver, Gold and Bronze to indicate the badges. I think there should be some sort of design like the Xbox 360 has for its achievements. You could still keep the colors by coloring the badge with Silver, Gold or Bronze.

Example would be like have an image of a mop or broom for the Clean Up badge.

Comment: As a note, some sites do have custom site-specific designs for their badges (i.e. one design for all the badges, in the 3 different colors: bronze, silver, and gold). Your request seems to be about having a different design/icon for each badge, which doesn't quite seem to be the same thing.

Answer (score 18):

Give each badge its own achievement icon?  I think it's a cool idea, but it's a lot of work.  I suspect that if Jeff was open to this, they'd solicit icons from the community (and not on a paid basis).  So if you really want this, I'd mock up a couple of icons and see if they like the look of it.

Comment: It's certainly possible, as they've already done this sort of thing with the Woot! badge. We just need the actual artwork (which is, admittedly, the hard part)

Comment: Do I sense a community competition?

Comment: Doubt it - how many programmers do you know who can work photoshop passably? :P

Comment: You might have some takers if a badge were awarded for coming up with good artwork. :)

Comment: Hey, if Jon Skeet can use Paint to write code, I can use Paint to make a pretty badge.

Answer (score 7):

We're going to start shipping physical badges soon.  Update your profile with your address and your solid gold, solid silver, and solid bronze badges will arrive in the mail in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Time to drink, for those playing the stack overflow podcast drinking game ;-)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Citizen Patrol]

[image: Commentator]

[image: Scholar]

[image: Tumbleweed]

Etc... :-]

*[Achievement Generator](http://teamfortress2.fr/achievements.php?eng)*

Comment: I like these - and descriptive too.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my new vision for "Tumbleweed", as per [my comment here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-tumbleweed-badge/1579#comment2471_1579):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4IkC.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

I love the icon-idea. A Wall-of-Achievements full of icons would be sweet :)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know if I'd be able to find these, but here ya go...from [a similar thread.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38330/graphical-badges/38339#38339)

[alt text http://imgcash4.imageshack.us/img197/8514/badgeideas.png?0.6349713410095544](http://imgcash4.imageshack.us/img197/8514/badgeideas.png?0.6349713410095544)

By the way, I know these may not be the *designs* you are looking for, but I do think they look a lot better than the bronze, silver, & gold dots.

Answer (score 1):

The woot! badge for enthusiast and the more received advertisements (e.g. Android and Red-Gate) shows that the infrastructure is there if someone has gone to trouble of creating them.

The graphics could be time-dependent too, so a new badge could have a shiny corner like the sparking new pin it is, with older badges looking a little tarnished and in need of TLC (although not the Gold ones, obviously).