# Make badges sexier

Tags: feature-request, badges

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Graphical Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38330/graphical-badges)
>   [Will the badges ever have a design to them instead of just having colors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/will-the-badges-ever-have-a-design-to-them-instead-of-just-having-colors)

I think it'd be cool if the badges looked a little nicer. As it is now, badges are at the bottom of the user page, all smooshed together as colored bullet-points and text. Meanwhile,  other sites are doing badges - [Foursquare](http://foursquare.com/help/badges) probably most notably right now, and even the [Huffington Post](http://www.flickr.com/photos/maisonbisson/4624248273/). Each one is distinctive and beautiful. Some are funny and tell a story. It'd be great if Stack Overflow hired a designer to do the same thing, and instead of burying them on the profile, maybe put something like "most recent badge" near the top of the profile screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphical Badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38330/graphical-badges). Given the spartan design of this site, I'm not sure sexier badges would really fit in.

Comment: If the badges are too sexy, they could end up NSFW...

Comment: @James, so?  Who would visit SOFU sites at work?

Answer (score 6):

One thing I love about SOFU is that almost everything is pure CSS.  The only images are avatars, the site logo, the editing, rss & envelope icons and maybe a couple of ads -- oh, and the adobe/android tags.  This is the style of the four trilogy sites, very few images.

I think sticking a boat-load of images in just for badges would go against the minimalistic style the sites have.  I am open to the style of badges being changed, although I do think they look fine as they are.