# Please enhance the "Recently awarded to" badge page

Tags: feature-request, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)

There has been some discussion recently about [showing which question/answer has given you a badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge). Jeff has [already mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge/898#898) that the data needed for this isn't stored, so I imagine it would be a good deal of work to implement. I have an idea that *may* be less work, and is a different take on the previous feature requests for this.

The previous requests seem *user-centered*, in that the new feature would be something added for each user to look up info about which questions/answers gave them a badge. I'm thinking of a more *community-centered* approach: a way for the community to see which questions/answers were most recently awarded a given badge.

Tabs could be added to the "Recently awarded to" page for each badge: a "Users" and a "Posts" tab. The "Users" tab would be what is shown there now, and the "Posts" tab would show the recent questions/answers awarded that badge. I don't know if this would be less work than the *user-centered* idea: I thought that since only the last 50-100 recently awarded questions/answers would have to be stored for this, it might be easier to implement.

One source of inspiration for this came from [this answer that cletus gave](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-tumbleweed-badge/1759#1759) on a question about [the "Tumbleweed" badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-tumbleweed-badge). To quote cletus:

> I think the purpose of the Tumbleweed
>   badge is (or should be) to bring
>   attention to a neglected and probably
>   esoteric question. Unfortunately it
>   fails in that regard because we only
>   see what users are awarded badges and
>   not for which questions.
>
> So basically this badge would have a
>   whole lot more value if you could
>   browse the questions awarded
>   Tumbleweed.

This feature would certainly make the "Tumbleweed" badge more useful for improving the visibility of overlooked questions.

Comment: +1 I think that's an awesome idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm cross-posting this here because they're duplicates (referring to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/list-the-quesions-answers-not-the-users-that-received-a-badge)) and I'm unsure as to which should win out. After one gets closed, I'll delete it from that one, I suppose:

Maybe not have the questions displayed on the badge page, but in a user's profile, mark the question with the badge that was awarded for it. For example:

```
[25] How awesome is this place? [* Great Answer] [* Necromancer]
```

I know that finding where your badges is supposed to be part of the search and destroy fun, but honestly, I'm not going through somebody's entire answer history to find out what the heck they won't leave dead to get the Necromancer badge.  For question/answer specific badges, this is a solid idea, and would be really neat to see.