# List the questions/answers not the users that received a badge

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, answers, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)

Jeff [stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge/898#898) that a background process runs to figure out how many badges you should have. I can understand this design. It solves a lot of problems. I can also understand why it's then hard to figure out what question awarded you a badge.

But when you look at the Great Answer list it shows the *users* who received a badge. We should be able to show the *answer* that generated the badge I would think. Now Great Answer isn't too terrible because you can figure it out from a user's profile. But what about Necromancer? Or Tumbleweed? Or even Populist?  It would be really nice to see this information.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2327/feature-request-enhance-the-recently-awarded-to-badge-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always wanted the ability to be able to click on badges and see what actually was the recipient of that badge. I pretty much agree with this suggestion 100%.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not have the questions displayed on the badge page, but in a user's profile, mark the question with the badge that was awarded for it. For example:

```
[25] How awesome is this place? [* Great Answer] [* Necromancer]
```

I know that finding where your badges is supposed to be part of the search and destroy fun, but honestly, I'm not going through somebody's entire answer history to find out what the heck they won't leave dead to get the Necromancer badge.  For question/answer specific badges, this is a solid idea, and would be really neat to see.