# Is the Tumbleweed badge good or bad?

Tags: discussion, badges, tumbleweed-badge

I've earned a Tumbleweed badge — but that doesn't seem like a good thing.  Is it?  I initially thought "earning" a badge was positive, but it seems to me that the implication is that I asked a question that was too obscure.

So: is it a good or a bad thing?  Do I want to collect more?!  =:-)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-tumbleweed-badge

Comment: The Tumbleweed badge [was retired in 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tumbleweed-badge/info). Related blog post: *[Adios to Unfriendly Badges! Ahoy, Lifejacket and Lifeboat](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/)*. I couldn't find a corresponding meta post.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It encourages you to ask questions even if you think they are a little out of the mainstream. In this regard it is a positive thing, though not something I would be too excited about.

Comment: Indeed not - seems a bit pointless.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I ask a ton of questions that are slightly out of mainstream and I don't have this? WTF. I swear to god I this game is rigged.

Comment: @user27414, On the other hand, SE wants questions and answers that applies to most people and most people will be interested in, so the badge seems to be opposite of what it wanted. Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69061/159916

Answer (score 16):

The badge is a consolation prize, since you didn't get an answer.

Comment: Not much of a consolation... =:-)  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I was over the moon when I got my first tumbleweed.  I just wish there was an actual tumbleweed that trundles across the page when it happens; although that might be over-playing it.

Comment: @andras: You should post that as a request in the greasemonkey script ideas question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/greasemonkey-script-ideas-best-of-stackoverflow-greasemonkey-implementations

Answer (score 9):

Badges are always something to get excited about.  They are shiny and precioussss ...

[image]

Also a good way to find questions that you might have an answer for.

Comment: I think this image is copyrighted. Just FYI.

Comment: Pretty sure the fair use rational on Wikipedia would apply equally here?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Gollum.PNG

Comment: I was tempted to add this as my preferred answer.  They're all great answers but this one is very funny.  Thanks.

Comment: This comment is copyrighted by Me. © 2010 Voyager