# What is the tumbleweed badge for?

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of the tumbleweed badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-tumbleweed-badge)

I remember reading (or possibly listing to) Jeff explain the philosophy behind badges.

> "To promote good behaviour"

(I've paraphrased)

With this in mind what is the [tumbleweed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/38/tumbleweed) badge for. As it seem to promote at best esoteric behaviour.

Answer (score 9):

It's a consolation prize.

It's also a reminder that you have a question not receiving much attention, so maybe you need to revisit it, revise it and generally improve it. Or just delete it.

Comment: There are a few badges that are more "well, that sucks :-\. Here's a badge to make you feel better" ([Unsung Hero](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero) comes to mind -- it's certainly not encouraged that you get no upvotes on your answers)

Comment: @Michael - that's true. But the idea of it being a prompt to improve or remove your question just came to me.

Answer (score 4):

Being the recipient of this badge for one of my questions, it did indeed act as a consolation prize. More crucially, it made me rethink the nature of my question; both its wording, which was not as clear as it might be; and its relevance to this site.

Comment: Did you fix it and get any answers?

Comment: I ended up deleting the question. I came to the conclusion that it was irrelevant, ill focussed, and not crucial to what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I like to think that Tumbleweed is an interesting badge, it means that you had a question opened, but unusual. No one probably knew what you were talking about, except that it looked off topic. This could help to expand the scope of a particular site.

For instance, if I asked a question about a very odd programming language, one that clearly fits into SO, but maybe just isn't that popular, it'd be a tumbleweed question most likely. But perhaps with some time, someone would come and answer it, and ask another related question. Thus, the badge has a bit of merit.