# Badge request for heavy downvoters: punisher

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, down-votes, data-explorer

I wonder if there is such a query on [stack exchange data explorer queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries), similar to [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1718/up-vs-down-votes-by-day-of-week-of-question-or-answer) on user base who cast the most downvotes.

Comment: What good behavior would this encourage that the current set of tags don't?

Comment: Well, it is some kind of [tumbleweed  badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1576/168587)

Comment: I've seen worse ratios.

Comment: How would you ensure people don't indiscriminantly downvote stuff just to get the badge?

Comment: @IͶΔ Downvoting is beneficial to the site... particularly when questions or answers do not fit the quality guidelines. Many people are afraid of downvoting because they see it as a "punishment" but, really, it's in the site's best interest that people use the feature. That being said, Oded makes a good point... some people do stupid crap just to get a digital pixel badge.

Comment: Well, actually I visit some users' profiles after their "nonconstructive" comments, even though they are right in their arguments. I am not suprised at all "usually"

Comment: Why are you putting code block in your question? If you're trying to emphasize it, use bold or italics. There's no reason to use code markup.

Comment: @Catija It is habituate from SO, updated it, thanks for suggestion. About downvoting, I don't like "downvoting" and I rarely do it, instead I prefer comments about negative points and try to give suggestion or vote to close

Comment: Don't use code formatting for plain English on SO either. BTW, I downvoted to get closer to that badge - it's free on questions too!!!! Weeeee badgers!

Comment: ...if only there was a badge for "prophetic" dupe-closing

Comment: I agree @Cat, but why in the world should this be encouraged by introducing a badge for up/down ratio? Wouldn't it discourage upvoting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/461621) shows the ratio's:

```sql
select top 1000 
       id as [User Link]
     , UpVotes
     , DownVotes
     , case 
       when upvotes is null or upvotes = 0
       then downvotes
       else  DownVotes/Upvotes 
       end ratio
from users
order by case 
         when upvotes is null or upvotes = 0
         then downvotes
         else  DownVotes/Upvotes 
         end desc
```

The user you pointed out isn't even close to the top spot of this downvote/upvote ratio list, and I don't think it is a bad thing to be at the top here. I'm obviously slacking.

Eric Lippert can have the badge, as he [states](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277608/shouldnt-there-be-a-badge-for-heavy-downvoters/277609?noredirect=1#comment901130_277609):

> I reject the notion that a ratio is a valid measure. My intention was to have zero upvotes; I was trying to clear a downvote and accidentally upvoted. Second, I reject the notion that this makes me the worst of anything. **Downvoting adds far more value to this site than upvoting**. I have reviewed literally hundreds of thousands of questions and answers for free, and identifying the stinkers that make the world worse is a valuable service

I can't agree more. Communities needs heroes.

[image: ratios]

I think moderation towards quality is a positive behavior and down voting is certainly a good tool to signal any quality issues to both the OP and visitors of the post. If there should be such a badge it should be awarded for a substantial number of votes and the down vote ratio is above 10.

Comment: Yay! I am among the top 40 on that list!

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion congrats! But please don't make me feel I'm slacking  ...

Comment: First of all, I reject the notion that a ratio is a valid measure. My intention was to have zero upvotes; I was trying to clear a downvote and accidentally upvoted.  Second, I reject the notion that this makes me the worst of anything.  **Downvoting adds far more value to this site than upvoting**. I have reviewed literally hundreds of thousands of questions and answers *for free*, and identifying the stinkers that make the world worse is a valuable service.

Comment: Also, there's something wrong with your math.  The ratio of 1961 to 1 is 1961 to 1, not 980 to 1.

Comment: @EricLippert you're right about my math, I'll correct that. My answer isn't here to call you out as the worst of anything, or offend you if that is how you perceive my answer, I'll edit that out. You happened to be on the top of that query and given my deep respect for you I awarded you the imaginary badge as proposed by the OP. In my last paragraph I try to convey the same message as you: down voting is a good tool. Do I need to reword that resembling your comment?

Comment: @EricLippert I fixed the ratio bug, edited the answer a bit and added your comment in the answer. Are you OK with this revision?

Comment: Sure, that's fine. I'm just pointing out that describing someone as "the worst" of a thing is taking an editorial position, not reporting a fact. It is fun to try to spot this in clickbait headlines. "Senator X has worst voting record on abortion rights", for example, tells you nothing unless you know the editorial bias of the writer towards the subject; another writer might read the same statistics and conclude that Senator X has the best record.

Comment: @EricLippert I can hide behind the fact that I'm not a native speaker but in hindsight I see where it derailed. Sorry about that, I learned a lesson and keep it in mind when I review my other answers. Thanks for pointing it out to me.